# mod_authnz_ldap not finding objects but can't figure out why?

Tags: ldap, httpd, openldap

from the console I run: `ldapsearch -D cn=admin,dc=psikon,dc=net -LLL -W`

and I get an entry:

```
dn: cn=megatron,ou=Executive,dc=psikon,dc=net
sn: megatron
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
userPassword:: [password]
cn: megatron
```

so far so good?

So a vhost has a simple configuration:

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldapi:///?cn"
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin,dc=psikon,dc=net"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "[admin passwd]"

Require valid-user
```

When trying to login however, apache logs say:

```
[Fri Nov 30 09:14:57 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(403): [client 173.246.22.18] [11233] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldapi:///?cn
[Fri Nov 30 09:14:57 2012] [info] [client 173.246.22.18] [11233] auth_ldap authenticate: user megatron authentication failed; URI / [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][No such object]
[Fri Nov 30 09:14:57 2012] [error] [client 173.246.22.18] user megatron not found: /
```

My environment:

**OS:**       Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**OpenLDAP:** 2.4.28

**Apache httpd:**   2.2.22

I really can not figure out why this does not work since it seems Im making the same search with ldapsearch that works? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AuthLdapUrl is [wrong](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl). The format is ldap://host:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter - or more concretely ldapi:///ou=Executive,dc=psikon,dc=net?cn?one